# Convert this line from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++

I have a C++ method:-

```
const char *match(const char *str)
{
    if( *str == '\0' || *str == ')' ) 
    { 
        return str; 
    }
    if( *str == '(' )
    {           
                 // This is equivalent to str.SubString(1) in C#.
        const char *closer = match(++str);
        if( *closer == ')' )
        {
                                // Same here too closer.Substring(1).
                return match(++closer);
        }           

                // Wasn't sure about this.  
        return str - 1;
    }

    return match(++str);
}
```

What does str - 1 mean in C++? I am new to C++, primarily code in c#.

Thanks.

I have updated the method - basically it is is trying to find out if brackets match, i.e.

I/P:  "()" - Valid
I/P: "())" - Invalid. I have added comments inline for what i have understood, had issues with the "str - 1" line which doesn't seem to have an equivalent in C#.

Comment: There is no direct equivalent of this function alone. Please show us how this method is used.

Comment: I wonder where this code is from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `str - 1` line obtains the pointer that is one character before `str`. It is effectively obtaining the original pointer that was passed as a parameter, because it was moved one character forward with `++str` a few lines before.

A quick-and-dirty conversion would look like this:

```
string Match(string str)
{
    if( str.Length == 0 || str[0] == ')' ) 
    {
        return str;
    }
    if( str[0] == '(' )
    {           
        string closer = Match(str.Substring(1));
        // The original code has a hidden check for termination here!
        // If *closer was '\0', it would not enter the if
        // Let's keep that and avoid IndexOutOfRange.
        if( closer.Length > 0 && closer[0] == ')' )
        {
                return Match(closer.Substring(1));
        }           
        // The original just restored the pointer to its initial state.
        // Since C# strings are immutable, we can just return the original string.
        return str;
    }

    return match(str.Substring(1));
}
```

However, this creates a lot of extraneous strings. You should avoid that. One possible solution is to change the method to take an index as a second parameter, and use that to emulate the pointers.

```
int Match(string str, int i)
{
    if( str.Length == i || str[i] == ')' ) 
    {
        return i;
    }
    if( str[i] == '(' )
    {           
        int closerIdx = Match(str, i+1);
        if( str.Length > closerIdx && str[closerIdx] == ')' )
        {
                return Match(str, closerIdx+1);
        }           
        return i;
    }

    return Match(str, i+1);
}
```

And then write a small bootstrapper:

```
string Match(string str)
{
    int idx = Match(str, 0);
    return str.Substring(idx);
}
```

Comment: A question, how did you know there was a hidden check is that some C++ property? Interested to know.

Comment: @parsh: The "hidden" check is due to the fact that strings are null terminated. In C++, if the string is empty, `x[0] == '\0'`. This means you can test safely `x[0] == ')'` and it will return false. However, in C#, if the string is empty, `x[0]` throws.

Comment: In C++, if you check for `x[0] == ')'` and it returns true, you know for a fact that the string was not empty.

Answer (score 3):

It's pointer arithmetic. `str - 1` substracts 1 from the char pointer so that it points at a string starting one character previous in memory. It's the opposite of chopping off the first character -- it puts it back!

In C# you can't do it that way. But, for it to be valid at all, there should be a character that was chopped off earlier with a `str + 1`. You'll have to find that earlier operation in the code and save the original string so you can reverse it.

Alternatively, the `str - 1` might be just to offset a `str + 1` that comes later so that it never chops off the first character. Provided the pointer isn't used in the mean time, that <s>will be safe</s> logic will work on most platforms (although is undefined behavior).

Comment: Why does a character have to be chopped beforehand for this code to be valid? It's just returning a pointer.

Comment: @Boann - I'm not sure its safe. Invalid pointer is undefined behavior, you cannot assume it to be safe by using pointer arithmetics on it. Once the pointer is invalid - its UB whenever you use it.

Comment: @Boann - So does it mean the code would need to remember the value of "str" - the input parameter after each method call , hence a need to convert it into a "ref" parameter?

Comment: @parsh: I... do not know what you mean, but I don't think so. The `str-1` is simply a way to cancel out the `str.SubString(1)`, so refactor to prevent the substring operation in the first place instead.

Answer (score 1):

there is no possible analog in c# without `unsafe` flag.

c++ trates strings as pointer to array of char( char *).

c# trates string as instance of class.

c++ allows pointer arithmetic.

Usual c# (without unsafe code) does not allow these operations

Comment: hum, I was sure that @parsh wanted to convert this code to c#

Comment: I wanted to understand the meaning of that sentence, before trying to convert it :-)